# How to make generic ADT in java?

Tags: java, adt

I had wrote my code for queue ADT but it is not generic. I don't know how to convert my code to generic ADT. Anyone can help me figure out how to change my code in order to make it become generic ADT

```
public class DeckQueue implements DeckInterface {

    private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    private String[] cardArray = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];
public void enqueue(String newEntry) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= cardArray.length; i++) {
            if (cardArray[i] == null) {
                cardArray[i] = newEntry;
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    public String dequeue() {
        // get first element from array
        String front = null;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            front = cardArray[0];

            // shift remaining array items forward one position
            for (int i = 0; i < cardArray.length - 1; ++i) {
                cardArray[i] = cardArray[i + 1];
            }
            //set last to null
            cardArray[cardArray.length - 1] = null;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Card is empty");
        }
        return front;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return 0 == cardArray.length;
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.cardArray = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= cardArray.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "=" + cardArray[i]);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic rules of thumb are:

0. Start with the parent classes and interfaces. What methods does `DeckInterface` have and what types does it assume - should `DeckInterface` be generic itself?
1. Add a type parameter for the class. For some reason single letters are frequently used, instead of something more descriptive. We'll use "E" to stand for "element":

```
public class DeckQueue<E> implements DeckInterface {
    ...
}
```

2. Within the class, use this type parameter instead of the specific type, in both methods and instance variables. For example:

```
private E[] cardArray;

public void enqueue(E newEntry) {  ...  }

public E dequeue() {
    E front = null;
    ...
    return front;
}
```

3. Solve remaining issues. For example: in this class you need an array of the generic type. It's not possible to do that directly, for good reasons, see [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) One way to get around it is adding a helper method:

```
private E[] cardArray = createArray();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private E[] createArray() {
    return (E[]) new Object[ARRAY_SIZE];
}
```